# Find bitness (32-bit/64-bit) from Excel Application object?

Tags: .net, excel, 32bit-64bit, excel-interop

Is it possible to determine whether Excel is running in 32-bit or 64-bit from the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass?

**Edit**
The solution should work for both Excel 2010 and Excel 2007

Comment: Do you mean your program is not in the same process with Excel?

Comment: @Simon - I don't quite understand your question.  Excel is automated out-of-process, so no program can talk to Excel in the same process.  If I have an ApplicationClass object (through Excel interop), I'm wondering if I can determine whether the associated Excel process is running 32-bit or 64-bit (would have to be Excel 2010)

Comment: i.e. does the object model support information about bitness of Excel process

Comment: you could be in-process I suppose but ok, I got the question :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code should give you the "bitness" of Excel.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
if (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(app.HinstancePtr) == 8)
{
    // excel 64-bit
}
else
{
    // excel 32-bit
}
```

EDIT: here is another version that should work for previous versions of Excel as well. Just pass an ApplicationClass reference to it:

```
    public static ExcelVersion GetExcelVersion(object applicationClass)
    {
        if (applicationClass == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("applicationClass");

        PropertyInfo property = applicationClass.GetType().GetProperty("HinstancePtr", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        if (property == null)
            return ExcelVersion.Excel;

        return (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(property.GetValue(applicationClass, null)) == 8) ? ExcelVersion.Excel2010_64 : ExcelVersion.Excel2010_32;
    }

    public enum ExcelVersion
    {
        Excel, // before 2010, so 32 bits
        Excel2010_32,
        Excel2010_64
    }
```

Comment: I wanted to suggest this one too, but I refrained from doing so, because it only works with Excel 2010.

Comment: @Daniel - Is there a solution that works with Excel 2007 as well.  In fact, the purpose of my question is to determine whether I'm running 64-bit 2010 or 32-bit 2007.  I have a mixed environment.

Comment: I suppose I could try to get HinstancePtr and if that fails then I know I'm running 32-bit since the platform is < 2010 is only 32-bit?  what exception would be thrown?  My assembly is compiled against 14.0, but I do assembly redirection to 12.0 in app.config when I know 2007 is on the box.

Comment: My proposed solution does not work.  .net throws MissingMethodException before I have the chance to try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work (do it for me with Excel 2013 ff.)

```
try
{
    Type officeType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
    object excelInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(officeType);
    if (excelInstance != null)
    {
        string results = officeType.InvokeMember("OperatingSystem", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, excelInstance, null).ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(results))
            detectedExcelPlatform = results.Contains("64")?EDetectExcelPlattform.Force64Bit:EDetectExcelPlattform.Force32Bit;
        officeType.InvokeMember("Quit", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, excelInstance, null);
    }
}
catch
{
    // To Ignore
}
```

EDetectExcelPlattform doesn't matter, because it is only from my own code. Can be replaced with bool result.