# Check excel 2010 bitness

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel, vsto, office-interop

Is it possible to get office 2010 bitness using **getBinaryType()** function which is defined in kernel32.dll something like this.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool GetBinaryType(string lpApplicationName, out uint lpBinaryType);

uint type;
GetBinaryType("applicationName",out type);
```

I have tried using application class as stated below but sometimes it will fail.

```
 public static ExcelVersion GetExcelVersion(object applicationClass)
        {
            if (applicationClass == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("applicationClass");

            PropertyInfo property = applicationClass.GetType().GetProperty("HinstancePtr", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            if (property == null)
                return ExcelVersion.Excel;

            return (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(property.GetValue(applicationClass, null)) == 8) ? ExcelVersion.Excel2010_64 : ExcelVersion.Excel2010_32;
}
```

Is there any another way to detect **office 2010** bitness?

Comment: Are you running in-process with Excel? In this case, just check System.IntPtr.Size.

Comment: @SimonMourier : I think System.IntPtr.size will return operating system bitness but It is possible to installed office 32 bit on 64bit machine so in that case I want answer 32 bit not 64bit which I will get using system.IntPtr.size

Comment: System.IntPtr.Size will return the executing process bitness.

Comment: @SimonMourier : yes, you are right but I want this functionality in installer class no interaction with excel application.

Comment: fwiw, Microsoft recommends against running x64 Office 2010 at all, unless you have a very good reason to _need_ that edition.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn : I need to made an installer which can be able to replace some dll files in certain location if it found installed office version is 64bit.

Comment: GetBinaryType() would work, but there's a chicken-and-egg problem.  You don't know where the .exe file is installed without knowing whether it is the 64-bit or 32-bit version.  File system redirection makes it doubly troubly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187565/find-bitness-32-bit-64-bit-from-excel-application-object

Comment: @DavidBrabant : I have tried this but in some cases where two or more office version is installed it's failed over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is

1) open the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\LocalServer
```

(the guid means "Excel Application")

2) extract Excel's .EXE path from the key's default value (you want to remove all command line arguments)

3) use `GetBinaryType` on the path.

Comment: In some machine, I am not able to find out this registry key even though office 2007 and office 2010 is installed on that machine.

Comment: Strange. That could be a X64/X86 issue. What about `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\LocalServer` (for 32-bit programs)?

Comment: This registry key is not exist in 32 bit system but as you said it is in 64bit system. You are right it could be 32bit and 64bit system problem. but can I now make an assumption that in x86 machine "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\LocalServer" will exist and in x64 bit "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{00024500-0000-0000-C000-‌​000000000046}\LocalServer" will exist.